# How to get an access token after loginAndEnrollAccount ()

Tags: ios, swift, azure-ad-msal, intune

I was getting an access token by calling MSAL's acquireTokenSilently () and acquireTokenInteractively ().
However, I later found out that I needed to receive an app protection policy, and when I looked into how I needed to incorporate the Intune SDK into my app.
Since it was stated on the official page that loginAndEnrollAccount () must be used to receive the app protection policy, I called loginAndEnrollAccount () and signed in.
After that, I would like to know how to get an access token.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7c6Cw.png)

Even if I use acquireTokenInteractively (), I am prompted to sign in, and I get a message that it violates the app protection policy and I cannot sign in.
I can sign in with loginAndEnrollAccount () but I didn't know how to get an access token.
Does the Intune SDK have a function to get an access token?

Comment: You should only call `loginAndEnrollAccount` if your app *doesn't use MSAL*.  Since you are using MSAL you should call `registerAndEnrollAccount` *after* you have successfully authenticated with MSAL. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/developer/app-sdk-ios

Comment: thank you for your answer.
User authentication with MSAL is blocked by the app protection policy. (Added an image of the error message to the question)
Is this a problem with MS Intune?
The app under development is subject to the app protection policy as a custom app.

Comment: It's hard to say; There is a lot of config required in your app to use app protection; You need the app registration client id set up correctly in your app.  Is your device managed by InTune?  Does your conditional access policy require a managed device?  Is there anything useful if you click "more details"?  It is possible that there is a policy config problem; You need to be able to log in before you can get the app policy.  At the moment you have a catch-22

Comment: > You need the app registration client id set up correctly in your app
It is set.
> Is your device managed by InTune?
yes
> Does your conditional access policy require a managed device?
no.
All iOS or Android devices.
> Is there anything useful if you click "more details"?
I did not understand. excuse me.
> It is possible that there is a policy config problem; You need to be able to log in before you can get the app policy
Is it correct to call registerAndEnrollAccount () after acquireTokenSilently () or acquireTokenInteractively ()?

Comment: As you say, Intune and MSAL have so many elements that it takes a lot of time to understand.
Also, there is little information and it is difficult to find it.
I am impressed to be able to consult with a knowledgeable person like you.
Thank you

Comment: If you look in the screen shot you posted there is a link to "More details" - If you tap that it will show some more diagnostic information.  You should call one of those methods to acquire a token before calling `registerAndEnrollAccount` - After the enrolment occurs you should see a prompt to restart the app as it is now being managed.

Comment: As a result of trial and error, one solution may have been found.
When I checked "Use conditional access control of the app" in the session column of the conditional access policy, the sign-in was successful and I was able to get an access token.
Nothing is set in Cloud App Security.
Does that mean you can sign in?